# Forwarding traffic from network interface to a zerotier interface

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables, wine

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- ZeroTier 1.4.6 (latest stable package)
- Wine 4.17 (latest development package)

I'm trying to host a Red Alert 3 LAN session (using wine) on my system and would like to use zerotier since I'm behind a CGNAT setup.

Zerotier works perfectly as far as connecting with other systems on the same (zerotier) network. But I'm not able to view other players in the network lobby. Using wireshark I was able to find that the udp packets that are required by RA3 to work properly were getting transmitted only on the LAN interface and were not being forwarded to the zerotier network interface at all.

My next attempt(s) at this was using a tool to force wine to use the zerotier interface.

1. [small bind program in C which you can load using LD_PRELOAD](https://gist.github.com/stefansundin/e4fce00d97f7694c7a27)
2. [using a script to create namespaces and bind interfaces to it](https://gist.github.com/anurupr/68674675bcc6bef4460c3f399e9641e8)
3. [using firejail](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail)

   Reasons why these failed in the same order:
4. Because it didn't support udp
5. This worked initially. But it wasn't stable and it wasn't consistent. Sometimes, the other player would see me in the lobby but I wouldn't be able to see them. And other times it was the opposite. Also, I had to run this as root, which is not a good thing while using wine. So this option didn't help but it helped me understand a few things.
6. It was able to bind to that interface, but unfortunately I wasn't able to use the same IP  ( it generates another IP on the same subnet ) and I wasn't getting an output as I did when I used option #2. I even tried adding the IP address to the zerotier network interface from `my.zerotier.com` UI. It didn't help.

Besides this I was trying a lot of iptables configs but that didn't help. I enabled ipv4 forwarding via sysctl too. I still think this can be solved via iptables. [This](https://gist.github.com/anurupr/c04fd5014fb0bf23b08b76d8701585c2) is the latest attempt what I have so far ( in form of a bash script )